# FFmpeg / libav / Avconv settings to add higher contrast to a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libav

I successfully convert videos to mp4 from images turning the video black and white, is there a way to add contrast and brightness to balance the higher contrast so that it looks sharper? Here is the line i use at the moment successfully

```
avconv -y -r 24 -i images%04D.png -i music.wav -vcodec libx264 -vf format=grey -strict experimental -acodec aac video.mp4
```

Comment: With ffmpeg you can use curves filter to add contrast.

Comment: how do you use curves? @Rajib

Comment: You should take a look at [this](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#curves-1). You used avconv so I did not provide an answer. I don't use avconv and so I'm not sure.

Comment: you are right @Rajib - curves and presets don't work with avconv at all! just ffmpeg